# PostBackTrigger for FileUpload functionality inside a GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, triggers, postback

I have an asp:GridView control inside a .aspx page that the user can add several rows of data to. The user must also be able to attach a file to each row of data added.

For this I use the following inside the GridView:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Upload" HeaderStyle-Width="120px">
     <EditItemTemplate>
         <asp:FileUpload ID="fuUploadLocation" runat="server" Width="98%" TabIndex="18" />
     </EditItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Then to save the location of the file upload I use the RowUpdating event in code-behind to set the value etc.

The problem is I can't register a PostBackTrigger for the control on the html as it doesn't pick it up as it's inside the GridView. I've tried setting it dynamically from other examples but can't seem to get this to work, the result being my FileUpload's FileName is always empty and the file then doesn't save correctly.

Any suggestions would be awesome.

Thanks

Comment: You can use  Ajax asynch File Uploader for your problem.                                                http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/AsyncFileUpload/AsyncFileUpload.aspx

Comment: I've used the AsyncFileUploader but I have an issue that it seems quite a few people have. I keep getting an error in the upload stating “The file attached is invalid”. I've googled some fixes and most say to set the ClientIDMode="AutoID" either on the control itself or in the web.config but since I'm using this in a GridView I keep getting the same error regardless of whether I set ClientIDMode.

Answer (score 0):

On Gridview row databound you have to find the file upload control and then add it to your UpdatePanel postback trigger.

Comment: Yes, obviously. As I've stated I've tried certain ways to get this done but it still doesn't work and the file still doesn't save correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I've not found a solution to my problem but I did work around it (sort of). I know just add a link to the grid, when user clicks it sends ID through via querystring, a new page opens that handles the entire upload process and returns the url of the saved document.

Not ideal but it works and saved me hours of frustration.

Answer (score 0):

In the OnItemDataBound event handler of the grid need to call ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this).RegisterPostBackControl(ControlID);

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post but for anyone that is stuck with it, you need to add the following to your control as stated in the other answers.

```
protected void ItemDataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button myButton = (Button)e.Item.FindControl("myButton");

    if (myButton != null) 
        ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page).RegisterPostBackControl(myButton);
}
```

You also need to change the enctype in your form tag to the following e.g.:

```
protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Page.Form.Attributes.Add("enctype", "multipart/form-data");
}
```

It should then work without an issue.